# Disable collaspsingtoolbar expand

Tags: android, imageview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I've got an issue and I'm not able to fix it. 
I would like my collapsing toolbar not to be expandable if i have no image to set.
In my fragment i set the imageview visibility to GONE when there is not image to be set, but by doing so my toolbar just disappear (no more title, no more menu accessible).
Does someone know how to disable the collapsing toolbar from expanding ?

my XML

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/landscape"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabLayout" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/menu_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

In my first fragment is set the imageview visibility to VISIBLE and in my second fragment i set its visibility to GONE.

If someone have so idea it would be great !

Comment: Have you tried invisible? (as opposed to gone) That hides the view but maintains is position.

Comment: Well, the problem with invisible is that my collapsingtoolbar is expandable and i don't want it to be :(

Answer (score 0):

In Fragment,

> `mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(false, false);`

and

> `mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` *// in your case NestedScrollView*

Toolbar will never expand.